# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. Error Cmake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to run a python script, but I stumble upon the following errors while running it.

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
P2PSP_LIBRARY
      linked by target "splitter" in directory /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master
      linked by target "peer" in directory /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

This is my cmake error log.

```
    Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec2187325408/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2187325408
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec2187325408 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2187325408.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec2187325408' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec2187325408] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec2187325408/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2187325408/fast] Error 2

File /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec2407202235/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2407202235.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2407202235.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2407202235.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2407202235.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec2407202235
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2407202235.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2407202235.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec2407202235 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2407202235.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec2407202235' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec2407202235] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec2407202235/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec2407202235/fast] Error 2


Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec1093226452/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec1093226452
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1093226452 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1093226452.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec1093226452' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec1093226452] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec1093226452/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec1093226452/fast] Error 2

File /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTryCompileExec3293591889/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3293591889.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3293591889.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3293591889.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3293591889.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3293591889
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3293591889.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3293591889.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3293591889 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3293591889.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3293591889' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec3293591889] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/billy/Desktop/p2psp-console-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec3293591889/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3293591889/fast] Error 2
```

I have been trying different solutions. But the same error occurs again and again. Can anyone suggest me a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Please tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers (it didn't find the P2PSP library), and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask] and please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Florian I tried to compile make.py and i got some errors which are in my description.As,i came to know that Cmake gave me some errors i tried to found out what the error might be.I came to know that there are some path problems.But as i am new to c++,i don't know how to solve the problem.I think i shared my research upto my knowledge.Any suggestions please?

Comment: If you don't have any experience with C++ or CMake helping with this problem is difficult. Just looking at it: [`p2psp-console`](https://github.com/P2PSP/p2psp-console) is not a standalone project. It needs p2psp library (see [here](https://github.com/P2PSP/p2psp-console/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L49): `FIND_LIBRARY(P2PSP_LIBRARY p2psp lib/p2psp/bin/ lib/p2psp/src/core/)`. So build and install [`p2psp`](https://github.com/P2PSP/core) first.

Comment: @Florian I have the whole library.when i am trying to run make.py i get this error  [i am following this manual](https://github.com/P2PSP/I-want-to-use-it).

Comment: Ask the authors of the script. For SO it seems way to specific.